# How to publish a WCF Rest Webservice?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, rest, iis

My App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/webservice" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I published my webservice to the `http://localhost/webservice` target but when I open`http://localhost/webservice/` in my browser I get this:

```
localhost - /webservice/

[To Parent Directory]

 11/9/2015 10:30 AM        <dir> bin
 11/9/2015 11:23 AM           58 WcfJsonRestService.Service1.svc
 11/9/2015 11:22 AM          481 Web.config
```

This works well in debug mode. I just do `http://localhost/webservice/getUsers` and I receive a list of users. The problem occurs when I publish the webservice to the IIS because `http://localhost/webservice/getUsers` returns `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your site have authentication in IIS? Check in your site's basic settings in "connect as"

Comment: @RGdent i have the option "Application user (pass-through authentication)".

Comment: yes next to the "Connect as..." click on "Test Settings..."  There should be two Results: "Authentication" and "Authorization" they should both have a green check mark next to them.

Comment: Gives Yellow on Authorization (Cannot Verify Access Path (C....)))

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis#03), this helped me with this issue check step 3 for Authentication but also good article. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

> You can configure anonymous authentication by using the default
>   anonymous user account (IUSR), or you can set up a local user account
>   for anonymous users.

1. In Features View of IIS Manager, double-click Authentication.
2. On the Authentication page, select Anonymous Authentication.
3. In the Actions pane, click Edit to set the security principal (user credentials) under which anonymous users will connect to the site.
4. In the Edit Anonymous Authentication Credentials dialog box, select one of the following options:

   - If you want to configure a specific user account that IIS uses to access your site or application, select Specific user. Then click Set to open the Set Credentials dialog box, and enter a user name and password for the identity. Then click OK.
   - If you want IIS processes to run by using the account that is currently specified on the property page for the application pool, select Application pool identity. By default, this identity is the IUSR account. (Important: If you use the IUSR account, you grant anonymous users all the internal network access associated with that account.)
5. Click OK to close the Edit Anonymous Authentication Credentials dialog box.

You can use [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis#03) link as reference.